# MySQL SELECT all people matching X and then all in each person's household

Tags: mysql

I have two tables I need to query to print a list - `PURCHASE HISTORY` and `PEOPLE`

```
PURCHASE HISTORY
----------------
purchase_txnid...purchase_date...purchase_userid...purchase_productid

PEOPLE
------
people_householdid...people_userid...people_street...people_city...people_state...(etc)
```

I need to get everyone in `householdid` where someone has purchased `productid = "X"` (basically a list of everyone at any house where `SOMEONE` has purchased the product) and then display each of their purchase histories.

`PURCHASE HISTORY` has seven distinct products and `320,000` records.

Right now, I'm querying all people, `RIGHT JOIN`ing the purchase history to select people who purchased `"X"`, and then iterating through the results and, with each result, querying to `SELECT` everyone in that household and each of their purchase histories. It's extremely slow as there are `45,000` people and `320,000` purchases.

Any ideas as to how I can **merge this into a single query or optimize** it?

### UPDATE

Here are the queries:

```
$buyers = $db->get_results( "   SELECT people.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birth_date, CURDATE() ) AS age FROM people
                                RIGHT JOIN purchase_history ON purchase_history.purchase_userid = people.userid
                                WHERE people.region=$region AND purchase_history.purchase_productid = 'D'
                                GROUP BY people.userid
                                ORDER BY street_name ASC, street_suffix ASC, street_num ASC, street_unit ASC, household_id DESC, birth_date ASC
                            " );

foreach( $buyers as $buyer ){
    $in_household = $db->get_results( "SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birth_date, CURDATE() ) AS person_age FROM people WHERE household_id = '$buyer->household_id' ORDER BY birth_date ASC" );
    foreach( $in_household as $person ){
        $purchases = $db->get_results( "SELECT * FROM purchase_history WHERE purchase_userid='$person->userid'" );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between PURCHASE HISTORY AND PEOPLE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT peopleB.userid, peopleB.* FROM purchase
JOIN people AS peopleA ON peopleA.people_userid = purchase_userid
JOIN people AS peopleB ON peopleB.people_householdid = peopleA.householdid
WHERE purchase.purchase_productid = "X"
```

You can speed up this query by adding these indices to your tables:

```
CREATE INDEX productid ON purchase (purchase_productid)
CREATE INDEX householdid ON people (people_householdid)
```

I assume `people_userid` is already your primary key in `people`, otherwise you should make it unique:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX userid ON people (people_userid)
```

---

**EDIT** - You asked for the complete purchase history:

```
SELECT peopleB.*, phB.* FROM purchase_history AS phA
JOIN people AS peopleA ON peopleA.people_userid = phA.purchase_userid
JOIN people AS peopleB ON peopleB.people_householdid = peopleA.householdid
LEFT JOIN purchase_history AS phB ON phB.purchase_userid = peopleB.userID
GROUP BY peopleB.id, phB.purchase_txnid
WHERE purchase.purchase_productid = "X"
```

Note that this will give you people's data once for every purchase they made.

Also, I don't know if that query really works the way I want it to or how fast/slow it will be. You could also try reversing the colums in the `GROUP BY` line and see if that is faster.

Comment: This isn't giving me unique records but repeating them and is taking forever to run.

Comment: I updated the query to return unique users and added some indices that might make it faster.

Comment: This gets me right there and is fantastic, but I'm missing one thing - each person's full purchase history from purchases. Is it possible to add this to the query or would I be stuck doing a second query?

Comment: I added a query that might work. I assume `purchase_txnid` is the primary key in `purchase_history`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery and a `join`:

```
select p.*
from people p join
     (select distinct p.people_householdid
      from PurchaseHistory ph join
           People p
           on ph.purchase_userid = p.people_userid
      where ph.purchase_productid = 'X'
     ) ph
     on ph.people_userid = p.people_userid;
```

EDIT:

If you want to flag the member(s) that made the purchase:

```
select p.*,
       max(p.people_userid = ph.people_userid) as IsPurchaser
from people p join
     (select p.people_householdid, p.people_userid
      from PurchaseHistory ph join
           People p
           on ph.purchase_userid = p.people_userid
      where ph.purchase_productid = 'X'
     ) ph
     on ph.people_userid = p.people_userid
group by p.people_userid
```

Comment: I don't have householdid in purchases - just the userid. householdid only exists in the people table.

Comment: @Joe-NewNine . . . Of course not.  That would make the problem easy.  Fixed.